# Can't build python package because C++ compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, std

I have tried to install python package that have C++ dependency under Windows 11 (in Google Colab / Kaggle notebook package builded just fine)

full log:

```
C:\Users\Dima>py -m pip install git+https://github.com/bayarpark/candlewick.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/bayarpark/candlewick.git
  Cloning https://github.com/bayarpark/candlewick.git to c:\users\dima\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/bayarpark/candlewick.git 'C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk'
  Resolved https://github.com/bayarpark/candlewick.git to commit f7ce4549ba1181491d02fb06ae8b807520befdd0
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: shapely>=1.8.0 in c:\users\dima\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from candlewick==0.1.0) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14 in c:\users\dima\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from shapely>=1.8.0->candlewick==0.1.0) (1.23.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: candlewick
  Building wheel for candlewick (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for candlewick (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [83 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick
      copying candlewick\simplification.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick
      copying candlewick\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick\psimpl
      copying candlewick\psimpl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick\psimpl
      running egg_info
      writing candlewick.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to candlewick.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to candlewick.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to candlewick.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'candlewick.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'candlewick.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3zfbu1yh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'candlewick.psimpl' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'candlewick.psimpl' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'candlewick.psimpl' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'candlewick.psimpl' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'candlewick.psimpl' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying candlewick\psimpl.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick
      copying candlewick\psimpl\bindings.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick\psimpl
      copying candlewick\psimpl\bindings.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\candlewick\psimpl
      running build_ext
      building 'candlewick.psimpl._psimpl' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\candlewick
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\candlewick\psimpl
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3zfbu1yh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -IC:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpcandlewick/psimpl/bindings.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\candlewick/psimpl/bindings.obj /std:c++latest /EHsc /bigobj -O3
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
      bindings.cpp
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(441): error C2039: 'bind2nd': is not a member of 'std'
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\numeric(23): note: see declaration of 'std'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): error C2760: syntax error: ',' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1623): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'psimpl::PolylineSimplification<DIM,InputIterator,OutputIterator>' being compiled
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): error C2760: syntax error: ',' was unexpected here; expected ';'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ',' following 'expression_statement'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): note: error recovery skipped: ','
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): error C2760: syntax error: '>' was unexpected here; expected 'declaration'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
      C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hhpm19fk\candlewick\psimpl\psimpl.h(1338): note: error recovery skipped: ')'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
```

As I understand there is incompatible C++ version. Because bind2nd was removed from C++ 17. How can I fix it?

The failing code is

```
std::transform (first, last, first, std::bind2nd (std::minus <value_type> (), stats.mean));
```

Comment: `cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'` , i think you best option is to download it and modify its `setup.py`  specifically `extra_compile_args` to pass the correct arguments to msvc `/std:c++14 /O2`

Comment: note that after you download and modify it you can still `python -m pip install path_to_downloaded_folder`

Comment: cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/std:c++14 /O2'

msvc doesn't support define C++ version :(

Comment: MSVC very much supports [defining the language version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170). What it *doesn't* support is options from Linux compilers.

Comment: Also std::ptr_fun was removed in C++ too

Comment: How to replace             std::transform (errors.get (), errors.get () + errorCount,
                            errors.get (),
                            std::ptr_fun <double, double> (std::sqrt)); 

?

Comment: split it into two options `extra_compile_args=['/std:c++14', '/O2']`